# How to save the results of various operations in a .txt new file in C

Tags: c, file, pointers

this is what is requested in the exercise:
I have a .txt file that they give me with the following information:

```
JOAN         1   70.5       85
TANIA        2   49         75
TOM          3   53         54
JEFF         4   80         49.5
SUSAN        5   89         90
KATHY        6   99         55
RAYMOND      7   22.5       75
```

**the program reads the information from this file and calculates the following:**

a) Calculate who obtained the diploma (Identity names, grades).

b) Arrange subject A in ascending order (you should identify student name,
student ID and subject B).

c) Calculate the average and standard deviation of each subject.

d) The above given data should be read from an external file. The data should be
saved in the format shown in the example below and should be displayed once
you run the program. Also, your output should be displayed on the screen as
well as copied to an external file.

I did part a), b) and c), I am missing part d), since I don't know how to copy all the results to a file, I was only able to copy part a) by taking the given file and copying it to a new file called New_Data .txt, Here what I did, a part of the code, in which only logor copies part a) of the exercise:

```
   ptrCf = fopen ( "lab1.txt", "r" );
   ptrCf2 = fopen ( "New_Data.txt" , "w" );

  while ( (data1 = fgetc ( ptrCf )) != EOF ) {
   fputc ( data1, ptrCf2 );  
   }
   rewind( ptrCf2 );

   if ( ( ptrCf2 = fopen( "New_Data.txt", "r+" ) ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "The file could not be opened\n" );
    } //end if
```

I want to copy the rest of the results: a), b) and c) in the same new file New_Data .txt but I don't know how to do

Comment: "The above information" I do not see it.

Comment: Please learn how to format. Your formatting mistakes hid a lot of info. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please upgrade the shown code into a [mre].

Comment: `ptrCf` and `ptrCf2` are not the best variable names. `in_file` and `out_file` are a bit more explanatory. Also, you open `ptrCf2` and then try to open  it again without closing it first. To write to `ptrCf2` you can use `fprintf`.